# Strong and Weak Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independently Poisson distributed random variables with parameter $\lambda = n+1$ ($n=1,2,...$). I want to check whether SLLN holds for $Y_n = \frac{X_n}{\sqrt {\log(n+1)}}$.

Well, it's pretty easy to prove that WLLN holds but it's hard for me to prove or disprove SLLN. I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma but with no result.

Comment: "I tried to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma but with no result." Please show how.

Comment: @Did Actually I tried to disprove SLLN for the sequence. I tried to show that  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb P(|\frac{Y_n - \mathbb EY_n}{n}| > \epsilon)$ diverges, what would prove the SLLN does not hold as it is a neccessary condition for SLLN to hold for the sequence.

Comment: @MadChemist  : It would help to define precisely what you want to show, i.e., what do you mean by  "SLLN holds for $Y_n$"?  Are you trying to show $(Y_n-E[Y_n])/n\rightarrow 0$? Or $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\rightarrow \infty$? Or $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_n-E[Y_n]) \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @Michael I want to show that $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_n - EY_n)$ converges to 0 or not almost surely.

Comment: @MadChemist : So how did you prove the weak law?

Comment: @Michael I used Chebyshev's inequality. $P(\frac{1}{n} |\sum_{i=1}^{n} (Y_n - EY_n)| > \epsilon) \le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} Var X_i}{n^2 \log(n+1)}$, which converges to $0$

Comment: @MadChemist : But the inequality in this case seems to be $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i+1}{\log(i+1)}$, which is a bit larger than what you wrote, particularly since the $\log$ is inside the sum (the $\epsilon$ part is not a big deal).

Comment: @Michael : you're right, I was wrong. But we can easily estimate the sum: $\frac{1}{\epsilon^2 n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i+1}{\log(i+1)} \le \frac{n(n+1)}{\epsilon^2n^2 \log(n+1)} + \frac{M}{\epsilon^2 n^2}$, where $M$ equals the sum of some finite terms of the sum as the function $x\over \log x$ is increasing. Is it true or I am wrong again?

Comment: You are right, $x/\log(x)$ is increasing when $x>e$. That is a nice proof of the "weak" version.  Unfortunately the decay $1/\log(n+1)$ is very slow, even if we sample at the sparse subsequence of times $n_k = (1+\delta)^k$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/\log(n_k+1)$ is not finite...it would be a different story if we had $1/\log()^2$. Thus, I think that using a 4th centralized moment (rather than variance) will work, I think if $X$ is Poisson then $E[|X-E[X]|^4] = E[X](3E[X]+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial argument that shows probability 1 convergence over a sparse subsequence.

As in my comment above, it seems best to use a 4th centralized moment: For any $\epsilon>0$ we have
\begin{align}
P\left[\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-E[Y_i])\right|\geq \epsilon\right]&\leq \frac{E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-E[Y_i]) \right)^4\right]}{\epsilon^4n^4} \\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon^4n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n E[(Y_i-E[Y_i])^4] \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{\epsilon^4n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j\in\{1, ..., n\} - i}E[(Y_i-E[Y_i])^2]E[(Y_j-E[Y_j])^2]\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon^4n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n E[(Y_i-E[Y_i])^4] \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{\epsilon^4n^4}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nE[(Y_i-E[Y_i])^2]E[(Y_j-E[Y_j])^2]\\
\end{align}
The second term is the dominant term and so by the bound that you gave in your comments:
$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon^4}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^nE[(Y_i-E[Y_i])^2]\right)\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^nE[(Y_j-E[Y_j])^2]\right) \leq \frac{C}{\epsilon^4(\log(n+1))^2}$$ 
where $C$ is some positive constant, 
which indeed gives us the $1/(\log(\cdot))^2$ as we wanted. Now you can fix $\delta>0$ and sample at the sparse subsequence of times $n_k = \lceil(1+\delta)^k\rceil$ to get probability 1 convergence over that sparse subsequence of times: 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}(Y_i-E[Y_i]) = 0 \quad \mbox{ with prob 1} $$

---

Edit: My original posted answer concluded too hastily that "standard nonnegativity arguments" imply convergence over the sparse subseqeunce $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ implies convergence over the full sequence $\{n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. However, while the $Y_i$ variables are nonnegative, their time average is not converging to a finite mean $m$, so it is not clear how to proceed by "standard" ways.

Comment: Unfortunately I concluded too hastily that convergence over the sparse subsequence implies convergence over the full sequence (see my edit).  So the above only proves convergence over times $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, it is not clear how to proceed to prove convergence over $\{n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. This seems to be a  difficult question, where does it come from?